# Why $\lim_{u\to 0}\ln\left((1+u)^\frac{1}{u}\right)=\ln\left(\lim_{u\to 0}(1+u)^\frac{1}{u}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I came across this issue while analysing $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)$ and need a little help understanding the logic:

$\displaystyle\lim_{Δx\to0}\frac{\ln(x+Δx)-\ln(x)}{Δx}$

$\displaystyle\lim_{Δx\to0}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{x+Δx}{x}\right)}{Δx}$ (logarithm properties)

$\displaystyle\lim_{Δx\to0}\frac{1}{Δx}·\ln\left(1+\frac{Δx}{x}\right)$

$\displaystyle\lim_{Δx\to0}\ln\left(\left(1+\frac{Δx}{x}\right)^\frac{1}{Δx}\right)$, 
at this point, to clear things up, the substitution $u = \frac{Δx}{x}$ is made, (hence, $ux = Δx$) so:

$\displaystyle\lim_{u\to0}\ln\left(\left((1+u)^\frac{1}{u}\right)^\frac{1}{x}\right)$

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}·\lim_{u\to0}\ln\left((1+u)^\frac{1}{u}\right)$

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}·\ln\left(\lim_{u\to0}(1+u)^\frac{1}{u}\right)$

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}·\ln(e) = \frac{1}{x}$

The question on the table is, I know according to limit properties that $\lim_{x\to a}c\, f(x)$ = $c\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$, but I don't understand why $\lim_{u\to 0}\ln\left((1+u)^\frac{1}{u}\right)$ = $\ln\left(\lim_{x\to a}(1+u)^\frac{1}{u}\right)$. I've been told its because the function is continuous, but seeing as I'm self taught and never actually sat through a Calc I class, that didn't mean much to me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I presume that there's a typo in the title.

Comment: You need to replace $x\to a$ by $u\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks @ParamanandSingh

Answer (score 3):

The [*definition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_functions) of $f$ being a continuous function at a real number $c$ is
$$\lim_{y \to c} f(y) = f(c).$$
[Note that there are other equivalent ways to define continuity.]

In particular if $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)=c$, then
$$\lim_{x \to a} f(g(x)) = f(c).$$

So if the limit $\lim_{x \to a} (1+x)^{1/x} = c$ exists, then
$$\lim_{x \to a} \ln((1+x)^{1/x}) = \ln(c).$$

Answer (score 3):

When there is a discontinuity, the limit and the function do not commute:

$$f\left(\lim_{x\to a}x\right)\ne\lim_{x\to a}f(x).$$

For example, let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}x<0\to0,\\x\ge0\to1.\end{cases}.$$

Then

$$f\left(\lim_{x\to0}x\right)=f(0)=1$$ while

$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$$ does not exist (left and right limits differ).

On the opposite, as can be show by an $\epsilon,\delta$ argument, a continuous function and a limit do commute.

Comment: (+1)  Clear and concise.  You might consider mentioning that it is the mere continuity of the logarithm that is used here.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that
$$
\lim_{u\to0}\log\left((1+u)^{1/u}\right)=\log\left(\lim_{u\to0}(1+u)^{1/u}\right)\tag{1}
$$
is that
$$
\lim_{u\to0}(1+u)^{1/u}=e\tag{2}
$$
and $\log(x)$ is continuous at $x=e$. That is, because of $(2)$, $(1)$ is the same as
$$
\lim_{x\to e}\log\left(x\right)=\log\left(\lim_{x\to e}x\right)\tag{3}
$$
and $(3)$ is true because it is essentially the definition of continuity.